# SQL Server 2014 Insert Stuff function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary
1               John
1               Sam


SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary, John, Sam
```

Hi, i'm using SQL Server 2014. I would like to know if it's possible to use the STUFF() function to **insert** the result into one column. The examples i see online are all retrieving. I tried to do it based on the documentation by it doesn't seems to be correct.

**Query**

```
 @"INSERT INTO ApplicationOtherInfo 
                        (ApplicationId, AppOptionCode
                         ) values 
                        (@applicationId, @appCode
                         )";

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + AppOptionCode
              FROM ApplicationOtherInfo 
              ORDER BY AppOptionCode
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Yes it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
DECLARE @Students TABLE (
    SubjectID int,
    StudentName nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO @Students VALUES
(1, 'Mary'),
(1, 'John'),
(1, 'Sam')

INSERT INTO SomeTable
SELECT DISTINCT 
        s.SubjectID,
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + StudentName
              FROM @Students 
              WHERE s.SubjectID = SubjectID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
                        as StudentName
FROM @Students s
```

If you select from `SomeTable` you will get:

```
SubjectID   StudentName
1           Mary, John, Sam
```

Comment: Have you tried my solution?